# Creating different GA account in firebase for particular usecase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

Is it possible to configure dynamic GA account in firebase for our CKYC usecase ?

For my project we created a new GA account. our usecase journey is using 3 different code-bases – Angular JS, Native & React-native. For Angular JS the events have been configured for the specific CKYC account in GA4.

But for liveliness module (built on android/ios native app), the events are configured using the firebase process. But when we checked the GA account linked in the firebase project it is the common thanks app account.

Is it possible to configure dynamic GA account in firebase for this usecase? I am also going through the GA documents but it says to link the firebase property/propertyID/app/etc.

Is it possible to configure dynamic GA account in firebase for my usecase ?

Comment: You ask the same question three times, but you fail to elaborate your existing situation and the situation you want to get to properly. Please improve your question.